# mongodb reference to document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am having an issue with this piece of code.
(Using nodes, express, mongoose to save documents to mongodb)

```
// We have an array that contains objects (365) of type 'Day' to be stored in mongodb. 
// In my code this array contains data :-)
let arrDays = []

// Empty array to hold reference to the _id of the created days
let arrDaysID = [];

// Store all days in the 'arrDays' array to mongodb using mongoose
Day.create(arrDays, function(err, days){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something went wrong " + err)
    } else {
        // Iterate over every 'day' object in mongodb and add a reference to           
        // the _id of the 'day' object inside the 'year' object
        days.forEach(function(day){
            year.days.push(day._id);
            year.save();
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is that instead of adding every _id reference in the 'year' object once, the _id reference is added multiple times. When the code finished running, about 140.000 references are inside the year.days array while there are only 365 days defined...

Any hints or tips are welcome.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#create_create) of `model.create` API, it is a `Shortcut for saving one or more documents to the database. MyModel.create(docs) does new MyModel(doc).save() for every doc in docs.`

This means, you are executing the forEach loop for every day added in `create` method making it an n*n complex function.

`365 * 365 = 133225` which is approximately equal to 140000 records.

I think this explains the problem.

> EDIT - Better Alternative

As per [mongoose insertMany API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany), `Model.insertMany()` is faster than `Model.create because it only sends one operation to the server, rather than one for each document`

Comment: this could be the answer, so stupid... :-) Will try this out asap

Comment: try using http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany as well. Just edited the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help that was the solution :-)